# Implementing infix in a CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a question regarding the construction of a basic context free grammar. My grammar is meant to parse mathematical statements. I have this so far:

```
E --> P
E --> E + P
P --> A
P --> P * A
A --> (E)
A --> n
```

I need to implement another non-terminal X which represents the infix operator (^) meaning to raise to a power. I do not know how to implement X in such a way that it is right-associative and has a higher precedence than both * and +. I am failing to understand how the above CFG enforces * to be of a higher precedence than +. Any explanation on these two questions (how * is higher precedence than + in the above CFG and how to implement ^ correctly) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `P` nor `A` can produce `x+y`. Consequently, `*` must bind more tightly than `+` in `x+y*z` or `z*x+y`.

Similarly, `P` can produce `x*y` but `A` cannot. So given that the matching production is `P*A`, the only valid parse for`x*y*z` is `P => x*y; A => z`. That makes `*` left-associative.

If you draw some syntax trees, this might become even clearer.